# (S)FTP only replace older file

Tags: sftp

I'm looking for a way to have (S)FTP only copy across a file if it's newer than the one already on the server. Ideally it would spit an error message listing the files that failed (but allow the others).

SSH and SCP aren't available, otherwise I'd script something using those.

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu locally, and I believe the server is also linux-based.

Comment: It's too bad that they're not available, because rsync could do this handily.

Comment: Which OS? etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script, maybe [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) ? (It can be just a strange idea of mine again.. if it's not what you want, sorry.)
Or if graphical, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/).

Comment: hrm, command-line ideally, but I'll have a play with FileZilla. Any ideas what options to pass to lftp?

Comment: Well... http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html >>  -N, --newer-than=SPEC    download only files newer than specified time || --on-change=CMD      execute the command if anything has been changed || --older-than=SPEC    download only files older than specified time || --size-range=RANGE   download only files with size in specified rang